# Add Apache virtualhost logs to PhpStorm project files

Tags: windows, phpstorm

I want to add some sort of shortcut to the `C:\Apache24\logs\coreshop_demo.local.*.log` files to the PhpStorm project files, so I don't have to navigate to the `C:\Apache24\logs\` directory and open them in the editor manually. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: 1) Create a symlink in your project folder? 2) Or add that folder as an Additional Content Root (the project itself is a Content Root). Just type "content root" in the Settings screen.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, additional content root worked. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-content-roots.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you can create a symbolic link in your project folder that will point to that Apache's log folder. It will be displayed in the Project View as an ordinary folder.

Or you can add that folder as an Additional Content Root. Such an entry will be displayed in the Project View panel as an additional node (the project itself is a Content Root already) and will be an IDE-only solution.

For that go to `Settings/Preferences | Directories` and use "Add Content Root" button: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-content-roots.html

[image]